# Требуется быстрая индексация большого объема данных

Tags: индексация, база-данных, производительность

Есть проблема с хранением и индексацией больших объемов данных. У меня есть данные с уникальным ключом длиной 40 байт. Мне нужно сохранить эти ключи с обязательной проверкой на уникальность.

Количество ключей может быть несколько миллиардов. И скорость записи должна быть не менее 20 000 в секунду.

Я попытался с помощью MySQL, но база данных работает пока не кончится оперативная память, после чего скорость записи резко падает.

Есть идеи как можно индексировать быстро и много?

Comment: Если сейчас это текстовый файл (в \*nix), то попробуйте просто sort -u.

Только места на дисках (в том числе в /tmp) должно быть много. Может быть в несколько раз больше, чем размер Вашего файла.

Comment: Можно попробовать фильтр какой-нибудь сделать, например фильтр Блума, для проверки на уникальность ключа-  
то есть начинаем последовательный перебор ключей, добавляя каждый новый ключ в фильтр, при этом проверяем, что говорит фильтр и если фильтр показывает, что такой ключ уже есть, то придется проверять сий факт ища вхождение ключа с начала файла до текущей позиции.  
Потребление памяти сократится в разы.

Answer (score 5):

40 байт. 
Это число или  строка?

@shved
Есть книга "Mysql оптимизация производительности" там отдельный раздел про индексы(стр. 135). Индексирование очень сложная тема и для таких объемов данных, за 5 минут не сделаешь эффективное решение.
Самое логичное - это уменьшить размер ключа до 5 байт(1 триллион) если это возможно.
Тогда производительность и потребление памяти, сократится в несколько раз.
Другие методы оптимизации в основном направлены на распределение нагрузки и потребуют дополнительные затраты на оборудование.

Если количество уникальных 'ид' больше миллиарда, то разумнее разработать дерево поразрядного доступа.
Скорость обработки запросов всегда равна - 
O(разрядов числа).

То есть для 'ид'

```
 1. 67 поиск выполнится за O(2)
 2. 7267 поиск выполнится за O(4)
 3. 7263463463467 поиск выполнится за O(13)
```

Таким образом это самое быстрое решение для быстрой индексации.
Возможно создать реализацию, использующую файловую систему(папки - это разряды)

Она предоставляет следующие методы:

1. вставка()                      - O(разрядов)
2. поиск()                         - O(разрядов)
3. удаление_грязное()  - O(разрядов) - удаляется только значение,  а память выделенная на указатели путей остаётся.
4. удаление_чистое()   - O(разрядов + система_счисления) - удаляются и указатели путей и сам узел, вместе с очисткой соседних указателей.

Недостатки:

- Большое потребление памяти так как каждый разряд, каждого 'ид' - это указатель, и если он инициализирован то содержит массив указателей на другие узлы.
- Сложности с полной очисткой памяти. Вроде бы для полной очистки надо ходить по соседним указателям и заставлять ссылаться на еще существующих соседей.
- Трудоёмко получить отсортированную последовательность всех значений дерева.
- Порядок добавления элементов невозможно определить.

Преимущества:

- Быстрая запись, чтение и удаление(грязное).
- Возможность в качестве индекса иметь большие числа(128-256-512 бит).
- Может быть потокобезопасен.
- Однозначно перспективный алгоритм индексации будущего. Правда не ближайшего..

---

Ну вообще я не знаю как называется то, про что я говорю. Информации нигде нет.

*Поразрядная сортировка* - это отдельный алгоритм [вот](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).
А как на английском называется то что описываю не знаю.

Здесь структура данных, основанная на хранении уникальных ключей.
Каждый разряд числа, это структура в которой есть само вставляемое значение и стек[11] из указателей на соседние структуры, индексы этого стека соответствуют цифрам системы счисления.

Вот как выглядит поразрядный доступ вкратце.

```
struct УЗЕЛ
{
char разряд;
тип_ключа ключ;
тип_данных значение; // например текст или указатель на строку таблицы
УЗЕЛ * направления[11]; // указатели на соседние узлы
};
```

Поэтому если есть число 125
то поиск выглядит примерно так:

```
корневой_узел[1]->направления[2]->направления[5]->значение;
```

Получается только 3 прохода по указателям.
Поэтому она не зависит от длины массива.
Так как ключ уникальный, то и каждый УЗЕЛ есть уникальная структура. 
Сколько бы записей ни было, проход всегда выполняется за константное время.

У меня есть реализация на С++, но только на русском и без гарантии отсутствия ошибок.
Мне кажется она не очень эффективная. Там только вычисление разрядов числа отнимает 80% производительности при чтении.

---

В данном мини-отчёте видно что данная реализация поразрядного дерева полная противоположность std::map. Она в среднем в 2 раза быстрее создаёт данные и в 2.2 раза быстрее считывает их, но потребление памяти так же в 2 раза больше.

```
///////// Просчитано в 00:51:42 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## для 8000000. циклов-#- режим
конфигурации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 695.795712 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 2.9472656 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 329.392128 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 3.9033203 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 1.7949219 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 4.5214844 секунд

///////// Просчитано в 00:52:58 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## для 80000000. циклов-#- режим
 конфигурации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 6.925836288 ГБ
-время выполнения             :: 31.125000000000001 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 3.276713984 ГБ
-время выполнения             :: 39.806640600000002 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 20.091796900000001 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 46.719726500000002 секунд
```

---

Картинки чтобы лучше понять:
0 - это корневой узел.
Красным показан узел в котором лежит значение.

Вставка числа 256.

[image]

Вставка числа 2475.

[image]

Вставка числа 25675.

[image]

---

Объяснение почему расходуется так много памяти.
При вставке всего 3 чисел происходит инициализация 9 узлов, каждый из которых инициализирует 10 веток.
[image]

---

@avp 
Ответы на вопросы из комментария:

1. *Цифры, которые Вы привели в ответе - это для какого типа данных (80 млн. char[40] или int)?* Вначале size_t, сейчас char*[5-10-20-40-80]*(но char[x] >=0 && char[40]<=9, то есть по 10 веток).
2. *Чем и как заполняли (генерили) ключи?* Код генерации есть в коде который выложил.
3. *Исходный массив данных в памяти или на диске?* Во время тестирования всё в памяти висит. Это аналог std::map, так же перегружен оператор[].
4. *Данные копируются в узлы дерева поиска или в узлах только указатели (и м.б. смещения)?* Ну в коде можно посмотреть, он очень маленький(та же структура УЗЕЛ). Можно как угодно сделать. Я в основном смотрел на производительность именно механизма индексации этих контейнеров, на работу ключей. Возможности оптимизации этого алгоритма мне кажется довольно большие.
5. На счёт хранения во внешней памяти. Думаю тут да, всё зависит от производительности файловой системы и устройства, я таких тонкостей не знаю, тем более например как работают современные ssd revodrive.

Завершение:
Вывод:
К сожалению тех изначальных целей которые перед ним ставились не оправдал.
Максимальное преимущество в скорости по сравнению с std::map составило только 30 раз,
для маленьких ключей(28 бит) + в многопоточном режиме увеличивал производительность в 2 раза. Оптимальным для количества записей в несколько миллиардов - является ключ размером 44 бита.

- Ссылка на график [здесь](http://savepic.org/3201527.png).
- Дополнительное описание про угасание скорости работы std::map при увеличении количество элементов [здесь](http://savepic.org/3170807.png).
- Исходник ядра алгоритма(требует включения "iostream" и "map") [здесь](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bVXOOLkDX1FucubJv3oOR5ZenjjUvKiXb0TYRlC19M8/pub).

Все расчёты примерные, а не точные.

Введен специальный термин, актуальный для данного алгоритма. 
Чем он выше тем больше эффективность алгоритма, но при определенных условиях.
ПЗК(процент заполненности ключа). Показатель, отображающий отношения количества записей к максимальному возможному количеству уникальных записей ключа.

Формула получения:
ПЗК = (записей_таблицы *100) / максимальная_длина_ключа_десятичная;

- на 200 млрд. записей эффективность ПЗК ключа на 40 байт составит 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000136845%.
- на 200 млрд. записей эффективность ПЗК ключа на 20 байт составит 0.0000000000165436122510605534974%.
- на 200 млрд. записей эффективность ПЗК ключа на 10 байт составит 18.1898940354751083706%.
- на 200 млрд. записей эффективность ПЗК ключа на 9 байт составит  291.038304571572200869%. - уже не все влезут.

Из данных расчётов составлял точки на графике.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Просчитано в 22:24:25 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## количество записей: 20000000.
 циклов чтения: 20000000  ## тип ключа char[80] бит(320) - десятичное(2135987035
92091008239502170616955211460270452235665276994704160782221972578064055002296208
6936575) ## ПЗК(0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000936335270938439665431)-#- режим конфигурации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 8.383143936 ГБ
-время выполнения             :: 69.348632900000004 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 25.505792 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 37.407226500000002 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 65.607421900000004 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 41.221679700000002 секунд




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Просчитано в 22:19:43 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## количество записей: 20000000.
 циклов чтения: 20000000  ## тип ключа char[40] бит(160) - десятичное(1461501637
330902918203684832716283019655932542975) ## ПЗК(0.000000000000000000000000000000
0000000013%)-#- режим конфигурации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 1.249099776 ГБ
-время выполнения             :: 20.583007800000001 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 13.398016 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 21.249023400000001 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 19.960937500000001 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 23.823242200000001 секунд







/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Просчитано в 22:16:09 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## количество записей: 20000000.
 циклов чтения: 20000000  ## тип ключа char[20] бит(80) - десятичное(12089258196
14629174706175) ## ПЗК(0.00000000000000165436122510605534974%)-#- режим конфигур
ации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 254.68928 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 4.553711 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 9.46176 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 13.2880859 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 4.3212891 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 15.2597656 секунд







/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Просчитано в 21:56:26 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## количество записей: 20000000.
 циклов чтения: 20000000  ## тип ключа char[10] бит(40) - десятичное(10995116277
75) ## ПЗК(0.00181898940354751083706%)-#- режим конфигурации "release" -#- платф
орма  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 68.767744 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 1.1572266 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 9.744384 МБ
-время выполнения             :: 10.2978515 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 1.0996094 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 12.0136719 секунд





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Просчитано в 21:47:01 Вт 02 апр 2013  ## количество записей: 20000000.
 циклов чтения: 20000000  ## тип ключа char[5] бит(20) - десятичное(1048575) ##
ПЗК(1907.35%)-#- режим конфигурации "release" -#- платформа  x64
::: 2)формирование поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 102.4 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 0.3740235 секунд

::: 3)Формирование std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 77.824 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 3.3457031 секунд

::: 4)чтение из поразрядного дерева
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 0.3662109 секунд

::: 5)чтение из std::map
-затрачено оперативной памяти :: 0 КБ
-время выполнения             :: 3.3300781 секунд
```

Comment: @manking, IMHO поразрядная сортировка во внешней памяти (диск) это из области фантастики.

Но, даже если отбросить *реальность* по памяти (у ТС N больше 10^9 записей), то 40 байт это 320 разрядов, что дает сложность O(N \* 320), а скажем сортировка слиянием со сложностью O(N log N) даст O(N \* 30).

Comment: @avp
Если честно уже не помню точно. По моему 
поразрядная структура данных даёт не O(N * 320), а O(от 1 до 320).
Потому что весь путь указателей этого дерева и есть сам уникальный ключ.

Comment: @manking, т.е. Вы считаете, что время поразрядной сортировки **не зависит** от длины массива?

У Вас получается, что сортировка 10 и 10000000 16-разрядных чисел займет одинаковое время.

IMHO абсурд.

Comment: Обновил в ответе.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел свой старый код.
Эта структура не подходит для сортировки. То есть получить отсортированный массив оттуда может и можно только это вероятно будет стоить O(n*?)

То есть данным методом отсортировать массив int a[10000000] будет медленней чем другими способами.
А вот записать и получить данные будет быстрее чем например у std::map.

В ответе привел сравнение производительности c std::map.
Из-за ограничения аппаратной части(память) смог привести пример только на 80000000 элементов.

Comment: @manking, OK, разобрались. Я говорил о сортировке, а Вы о дереве поиска, которое быстро строится и в нем быстро искать.

Насколько помню, такую структуру еще называют N-путевым деревом. 

--

Вообще его можно приспособить для вешней памяти, только надо подобрать эффективные с т.з. чтения с диска размеры блока с данными и количество веток в каждом узле дерева.

Будет ли такой метод эффективней внешней сортировки - большой вопрос. Это сильно зависит от фрагментации диска при обработке/экспериментах, т.к. последовательное чтение с диска **на пару порядков** быстрее скачек по блокам.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но `O(2)` покоробило.

Comment: @manking, вот из-за лимита комментариев пришлось удалить один предыдущий, чтобы задать несколько вопросиков.

--

Цифры, которые Вы привели в ответе - это для какого типа данных (80 млн. char[40] или int)?

Чем и как заполняли (генерили) ключи?

Исходный массив данных в памяти или на диске?

Данные копируются в узлы дерева поиска или в узлах только указатели (и м.б. смещения)?

Какие у Вас ОС, объем RAM и CPU?

Comment: +1 Ответ - супер! Я допонял что-то из того, что не дошло в ВУЗе... Боюсь только спрашивающий это не оценит...

Comment: Пока разбирался скопилось очень много информации об этом алгоритме. Всю её не получится рассказать.
Позже выложу отчёт о работе этого алгоритма(+картинкой-графиком) с поддержкой формата ключей неограниченной длины. char[20-40-80] (теперь сложность точно O(разрядов)).
на данный момент я уже уловил законы которым подчиняется такой формат данных, и при каких обстоятельствах он может быть полезен для автора.

Также выложу код самого класса, в котором доступен только перегруженный оператор operator[](аналогично std::map работает , а все комментарии удалены для компактности).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте кластерную индексацию. Суть метода проста: сначала ваши 40-разрядные ключи по какому-нибудь алгоритму (можно тупо отбрасывать 30 разрядов) превращаем в скажем 10-разрядные ключи, в итоге все ваши триллиарды записей будут сгруппированы в 1024 кластеров, далее проводим индексацию внутри каждого кластера уже по 30-разрядному ключу.

Все нормальные БД поддерживают кластерную индексацию - например [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa174523(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @Barmaley, только вот у ТС не 40-разрядные, а 40-байтные (320-разрядные) ключи.

Хорошо, если значения первого байта случайны и равномерны - получим 256 кластров, а если картина радикально иная? 

Думаю, предложение использовать для кластеризации не 1, а 2 (или 3) первых байта, принципиально ничего тут не поменяет.

Comment: Разницы в общем-то нет в количестве байтов разрядов. Можно придумать алгоритм сводящий 320 разрядов к 10 разрядам тогда и получим те самый 1024 кластеров. Я просто об идее.